# How can I delete ubuntu from usb installer?

Tags: usb, format

I used a usb to install ubuntu to my friend. After the installation finished, I can't delete contents, what can I do to format it? Since this reading this as just being part of the system and does not allow deletion.

What can I do? I would appreciate an answer.
[image]
<sup>[Originally in Spanish](https://askubuntu.com/posts/451799/revisions)</sup>

Comment: Please use English to get help. Utilice Inglés para obtener ayuda.

Comment: @Danatela looks like you used a automatic translator to translate the question. But 1. The question doesn't make much sense to me 2.Will OP understand answer in English? or will he/she use a automatic translator(which would again make no sense) to get it into spanish?

Comment: Hi my main problem is tha t i cant erase the ubuntu instalation files  in my usb , even i try whit root and he dont let me , i try to change the instalation permits of the files but he dontlet me do that. I understand english whitout problem. I appreciate if you can help me whit that.

Comment: http://imgur.com/pLyOU5x  http://imgur.com/2DVo13P That is my problem.

Comment: Can you just format this USB?

Comment: I cant do that, that is my problem. I need format my friend usb. And as you can see he dont let me do that. I apologise for my middle english.

Comment: If you want me to see your reply, use @ with my name (@Danatela). Now, try to format this USB in Gparted. To install Gparted, type in Terminal: `sudo apt-get install gparted`.

Answer (score 1):

open disks from terminal as a root user and then try formatting

```
sudo su 
gnome-disks
```

Comment: Finally i can format that usb thanks for the help and patience of all the people who coment here.